# How do I make all sound output mono instead of stereo on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

My right speaker broke down and now only my left speaker works. How do I play all sound through only one speaker? The problem is if I play a song with stereo effect, I can't hear parts of it.

If I can't do it for all sound, is there a way to do it for rhythmbox and mplayer? Any other music/movie players that could enable this? I am using Ubuntu 10.10. Please tell me if you need any more relevant information and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`module-remap-sink`](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/Modules#module-remap-sink)

Comment: so i guess in my case, i should do this: load-module module-alsa-sink sink_name=front_mono device=hw:0 channels=1 channel_map=front-left ? and which is the file that i should add this line to ? /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ?

Comment: You need to have 2 channels, and remap them both to front-left. And it goes in daemon.conf.

Comment: Nothing useful in link, it's broken.